# Exception handling in the same function slows compile times by > 2x, why?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, compiler-construction, exception

I have a several-thousand-line project with a gigantic `main` (~800 lines).
The file containing the main function takes 7.94 seconds to compile.

The code is structured like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        /* 800 lines of code here */
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument const &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return EINVAL;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error const &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I simply change it to

```
void run(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* 800 lines of code here */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        run(argc, argv);
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument const &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return EINVAL;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error const &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compile time reduces to 2.48 seconds!

I can tell the culprit is the exception-handling code, because when I remove the surrounding `try`/`catch`, I get the same compile time reduction.

Furthermore, if I mark the `run` function as `__forceinline`, the compile time *increases* to 10.02! But if I do this after taking out the `try`/`catch`, then it goes down to a mere 3.27 seconds.

But what gives? What exactly does the compiler have to do that becomes so much more computationally intensive when the code is directly inside the body of the `try` block?

Notes:

- I'm compiling in RELEASE mode
- Microsoft Visual C++ Nov 2013 CTP compiler (native x64)
- Relevant compiler options: `/O2 /Gm- /GS /EHsc` (removing `/EHsc` also speeds up compilation)

Comment: I don't think anybody except the compiler designer(s) could answer the *why* question. Compilers can be pretty complicated and it is easy to trigger unintended consequences from seemingly unrelated design decisions. The primary job of a compiler is to be *correct*; performance is a secondary consideration. Note that I'm not saying that ensuring correctness in this case takes the extra time. I don't have a clue what it's doing, and it's unlikely anybody else outside the compiler team at Microsoft does, either.

Comment: Have you tried other compilers?

Comment: I am not be surprised that try/catch have an over head, but what surprised me, the performance difference between the two codes!

Comment: @Samer: Nope I haven't tried measuring the timing on other compilers. I'll post an update if I get more data.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Well I'm hoping maybe someone with more experience in compilers can make educated guesses.

Comment: @Samer: I just tried Clang 3.3-1ppa2~raring and g++ 4.7.3 on Linux (x64) and there was no real difference (it was around 0.05 ms, but that's probably measurement noise).

Comment: @Mehrdad can you use __try and __finally?

Comment: @Samer: Nope, I can't use `__try` because the function requires object unwinding (error C2712).

Comment: The runtime performance is the same though, right?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: None that I've noticed, but I haven't really cared enough to measure down to the millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the difference has to do with extra cleanup code.  C++ objects declared in a function are destroyed upon leaving it, so their destruction code is already at the function epilogue and (I think) stack unwinding - part of the exception handling process - can make use of that code. If you need to destroy all these objects *without* leaving the function - there's extra destruction code to be generated and managed, which can impact both build time and binary size.  Can you say if there's a difference in binary size?

Although frankly I'm surprised either impacts (time/size) is measurable. Are the '800 lines' exceptionally rich in C++ object creation?  (perhaps indirectly)